# C++ & Lua registering custom lua library at runtime

Tags: c++, qt, lua, luajit

I'm currently trying to implement LUA into my CPP program however I am having the following issue: I have a library in lua lets say lib.lua that I'd like to be ran into runtime so that other lua scripts can access it however I'm having issues with that here's my code:

```
    /* initialize Lua */
    L = luaL_newstate();

    /* load Lua base libraries */
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    /* add my path to package.path */
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.path = 'D://Game.Helper/Lua/libs/?.lua;'..package.path ");        

    /* require my the library */
    luaL_dostring(L, "_G class = require 'middleclass'");
    ^^^ THIS IS CURRENTLY THE CODE NOT WORKING ^^^

    /* load the script */
    luaL_loadfile(L, "d://Game.Helper/Lua/scripts/test.lua");

    lua_call(L, 0, 0);
    
    // clean it up
    lua_close(L);
```

the script is loading properly however if I don't require my library in the script itself it will return a nil value for it

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lua, when you declare a variable as `local`, it's only available in that lexical scope. You did `local class = require 'middleclass'` in one file, and then tried to use `class` in another file, which has its own scope. You need to either get rid of `local` so that `class` is a global variable instead, or move that line into the file that will use `class`.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the answer, I eliminated loader.lua and was able to edit the package path using : 

luaL_dostring(L, "package.path = 'D://Game.Helper/Lua/libs/?.lua;'..package.path ");

This allows me to able to require my library locally into my scripts perfectly however I tried doing:

luaL_dostring(L, "_G class = require 'middleclass'");

before loading my script and they will not recognize middleclass unless i declare it locally with require , is there a reason for that?

Comment: @CheekyLewb Did you mean `_G.class` instead of `_G class`?

Comment: You are a genius, thank you ! that fixed my problem!